# Is there a possible way I can join two tables in Prisma?

Tags: prisma

I'm trying to learn `Prisma`. I'm having a little problem since I want to `join` two tables using their `fullname`. This is my models in Prisma.

```
model User {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  email      String   @unique
  fullname   String
  department String?

}

model UserLibrary {
  id           Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  date         String?
  fullname     String?
 
}
```

So what I'm trying to do in `Mysql` is like this.

```
SELECT 
    userlibrary.date, 
    userlibrary.fullname, 
    user.department
FROM 
    userlibrary
LEFT JOIN
    user
ON
    userlibrary.fullname = user.fullname
WHERE department = 'FACULTY_DEPARTMENT';
```

Comment: What is the relation between the two models? Is it one-to-one / one-to-many / many-to-many? Joining on `fullname` just seems to be asking for trouble

Comment: Hi @Phil, I'm just trying to do a one-to-one

Comment: Then why not use a proper [relation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-schema/data-model/relations)?

Comment: Hi @Phil, I think I misunderstood your question, what I'm trying to solve is:

I have a bunch of same `fullname`,  so what i'm solve is join the two tables who have both same fullname so I can get their department.

Comment: With `fullname` not unique, you could end up with multiple rows for each `userlibrary` which is not one-to-one. Define proper relations and use the tools Prisma already provides for you

Comment: Hi @Phil, yes, its fine to have repetition since I'm just trying to collect all `fullname` in `userlibrary` , Is it it a good approach? I really appreciate your thoughts on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256587/discussion-between-stykgwar-and-phil).

Answer (score 0):

In Prisma, you can use the Prisma Client to do a similar query. I think Prisma did not provide direct support for window functions such as ROW_NUMBER().

Here is an example:

```
async function getUsersWithLibraryData() {
  const result = await prisma.userLibrary.findMany({
    select: {
      id: true,
      date: true,
      fullname: true,
      user: {
        select: {
          department: true,
        },
        where: {
          department: 'FACULTY_DEPARTMENT',
        },
      },
    },
    orderBy: {
      date: 'asc',
    },
  });

  return result;
}
```